# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedReader' : While passing file in the request parameter

Tags: python

I want to pass xlsx file as one of the request parameters (file) as below.

```
fields = {
      "file": ('1.xlsx',open("file.xlsx", "rb"),'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'),
      "payload" : ""
    }
```

But when I am passing a file like above I am getting this exception or error in python:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedReader'

Can anyone help on this.

Answer (score 3):

open() just opens the file for reading, you need to actually read the file bytes. Cannot tell fully from limited context, but if you don't need base64 then just drop that part out. The MIME type for binary data is "application/octet-stream"

Try this:

```
import base64

with open("file.xlsx", "rb") as xl_file:
    fields = {
          "file": ('1.xlsx',base64.encodestring(xl_file.read()),'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'),
          "payload" : ""
        }
    # do something with fields
```